# Problems adding fields in nested form through jQuery form railscasts episode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

i have followed the railscasts episode on nested forms(part 1 and 2) and having difficulty with adding fields using jquery, however when i click the remove fields link, the field gets removed.
Here is the code.
**In my question model i have**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tags, :class_name => "Tag", :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "question_id"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:keyword].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

**In my tag model i have**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :keyword, :question_id
    belongs_to :question, :class_name => "Question", :foreign_key => 'question_id'
end
```

**In my question form i have**

```
<%= form_for @question, :url => { :controller => "questions", :action => "create" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label(:name, "Request Question:") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= f.text_field(:name, :size => 72, :maxlength => 120) %><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :tags, :url => { :controller => "tags", :action => "create" } do |builder| %>
        <%= render "tag_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add new tag", f, :tags %></p>
<% end %>
```

**In my tag_fields partial**

```
<p class="fields">
    <%= f.label(:keyword, "Keywords:") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= f.text_field(:keyword, :size => 20, :maxlength => 25) %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</p>
```

**In application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
end

def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
end
end
```

**Then finally in my application.js**

```
function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

**I have checked to see if files are included in page source. The jquery works because 
other parts of my app are working. I do not get any error when i click add new tag. 
I have looked at other solutions, but none work for me. I cannot seem to add a field.**
Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you get html spit out when you click the add tag? (Like text formatted html that isn't injected into the doc) Or nothing at all?

Comment: @Msencenb hi, thanks, checkout my answer, not sure why it works but i think it has something to do with rails 3 and link_to_function. I was not getting any html at first. not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this on out, but i am not sure if it is the best way.
In **application_helper.rb** i changed the following line from this

```
link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
```

to this

```
link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')", :remote => true)
```

i am not 100% sure why it works, but i believe its got to do with rails 3 no longer having the link_to_function. Hope this help

Comment: I think the link_to_function still exists in rails 3 (you are using it in application helper) however it looks like the html sanitize function (h) was messing it up somehow. I would encourage you to test it without the remote => :true but also without the h and I believe it should work